# AJAX dynamic combobx isn't working, how can I fix that issue I have?

Tags: ajax

I am new into making AJAX, the webpage I am trying to do is with dynamic comboboxes, it is supposed to select a doctor from the database and then in the next combobox, schedules should appear there.

But the problem is when I select a doctor, no schedule appears there, I don't know what is wrong with my webpage, I am hoping someone can help me with that.

Code:

```
    function getHorarios(){
   $mysqli = getConn();
   $id = $_POST['rut'];
   $query = "SELECT rutemple FROM empleado WHERE rutemple = (SELECT hora FROM horario WHERE rut = '$id')";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $horarios = '<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $horarios .= "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[hora]</option>";
  }
  return $horarios;
}
```

There is the horario table:

```
CREATE TABLE `horario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `rut` varchar(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and there the empleado table:

```
CREATE TABLE `empleado` (
  `rutemple` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fnac` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` decimal(9,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cargo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `especialidad` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here the image of the problem I do have:

[image: Problem]

[image]

When I have to select the doctor, it should load the available schedules he/she have.

AJAX Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/cargar_doct.php'
  })
  .done(function(doctors){
    $('#doctores').html(doctors)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar las doctores')
  })

  $('#doctores').on('change', function(){
    var id = $('#doctores').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/cargar_horas.php',
      data: {'id': id}
    })
    .done(function(doctors){
      $('#horitas').html(doctors)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar las horas')
    })
  })
})
```

Table content of Horario:

[image]

Table content of Empleado:

[image]

```
function getDocts(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $query = "SELECT nombre, apellido FROM empleado WHERE especialidad = '3' ORDER BY rutemple";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $listas = '<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $listas .= "<option value='$row[rutemple]'>$row[nombre] $row[apellido]</option>";
  }
  return $listas;
}
```

Comment: Where are you using AJAX?  Where do you populate that element with options?

Comment: I have edited the question, What I want to know is how can I fix the issue I have, I want to load the schedules to the combobox of "horas" when I select a doctor from the combobox "doctor" (schedule of when does the doctor is available, 8am or 10am or 2pm). I guess the sql statement isn't right.

Comment: Don't *guess*, debug.  (Though one thing that is *certainly* not right about the SQL code is that it's vulnerable to SQL injection, which could always potentially be part of the problem.  That's worth correcting in and of itself.)  Take a look at your browser's debugging tools and check the network requests.  Are there any errors on the browser console?  Is the AJAX request made as expected?  Does it contain the value you expect?  What is the server's response?  Do you get into the `.done()` callback function?  Does `doctors` have what you expect?  Where does this fail?

Comment: What I found was this: Notice:  Undefined index: rutemple in C:\xampp\htdocs\dinamico\php\cargar_horas.php on line 6 (the first image in the post). I also uploaded two images of what's inside the tables "horario" and "empleado", the "rut" 4-9 belongs to Juana Perez which in the table horario has five schedule times where she attends. I still wonder why the combobox "Horario" doesn't want to load the schedules from Juana Perez.

Comment: That specific error doesn't make sense for the code shown, I don't see where you're accessing an index called `rutemple` at all.  Though you are trying to access `id` and `hora` from your SQL results, even though you never selected those.  The SQL query also seems a bit strange, because you're trying to find the `rutemple` value where that same value equals something else.  So you can just select that something else instead.  (Though, given the attempt to access columns you're not selecting, it seems that your SQL logic may need some work anyway.)

Comment: `"SELECT hora FROM horario WHERE rut = (SELECT rutemple FROM empleado WHERE rutemple = '$id')"` I improved on the SQL code, it works when I replace "$id" to "4-9", I forgot to mention the code behind the combobox of doctors which is up there. What I want to do is when I select a doctor, the relative schedules loads up in the next combobox.

Comment: Are there any errors now?  When you follow the same debugging steps as requested before, where does it fail?